# jQuery, javascript, find all unique links on page

Tags: jquery, arrays

I'm trying do do something like this:

```
   var items = $("main a").unique();
   var links = [];
   items.each(function (index, value)
   {
        links.push({
            href: this.href, 
            text:  this.text
        });
   });
```

the idea is to find all links on page and remove duplicates, producing an object with href/text pairs. But the above does not work, I'm getting "TypeError: $(...).unique is not a function"

Comment: which jquery version u using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling [`$.unique()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/) incorrectly. It is not a method of the jQuery object, it is an actual function. You really want:

`$.uniqueSort($("main a"))`

Also, learn to use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) instead of pushing arrays:

```
var links = $.uniqueSort($("main a")).map(function(idx, e) {
    return {href: e.href, text: e.text}
})
```

(Note: this `.map()` is the jQuery version, where the first argument to the callback is the array/object's index instead of the array element, because `$.uniqueSort()` applied to a jQuery object returns a jQuery object not a native JavaScript array).

Comment: Thanks, but using map(), "argument e" just returns array numeric keys, like 0,1 etc, how do I access actual values like href, and text?

Comment: got it, it needs second argument to access properties.

Comment: ahh apparently uniqueSort on a jQuery object does not return a real javascript array, it returns a jQuery object, and when you map against it, it runs jquery map not javascript map

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for unique in jQuery is :

```
$.uniqueSort()
```

`$.unique()` [is deprecated](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/) as of jQuery 3.0